# Redirect all the old url to new using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I had an old site implemented on liferay. All the links were like

```
www.site.com/web/something
```

I want to write a htaccess rule so that all the requestes with /web/* should
be redirected to the homepage permanenty...

Now for individual url i have wrote this.

```
Redirect 301 /web/contact http://www.site.com/contact
```

Is there a wildcard method or something for this?

Answer (score 1):

How about this which redirects */web/something* to *http://site.com/something*:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^web/(.*) http://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Or anything anything starting with /web/ redirects to homepage:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^web/.* http://site.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, staying within mod_alias, you can just use `RedirectMatch` to use a wildcard:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /web/(.*) http://www.site.com/$1
```